# How do I put blocks inline in drupal without layout builder?

Tags: php, drupal, block

I am a beginner in Drupal. I am having a problem putting inline blocks.
In layout builder, it is easy. add a section and put a block to the section.
But I am building a site without a layout builder module and control layout using block layout.

In Block layout, all blocks can be controlled only vertically, not horizontally.

How can I put multiple blocks horizontally?